JWT data, where to save it? and how? (React)
I have a valid Authorization Token from an api, I have saved this token with react in the cookies. now what is the proper way of reading the data within this Authorization token?
right now im using an npm package called jwt-decode
console.log(jwtDecode<JwtPayload>(cookies.get("at")))

which outputs:
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: 'Username', 
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: 'Admin', 
exp: 1717366278, 
iss: 'https://website.com', 
aud: 'https://website.com'

But, TypeScript is making it impossible for me to get the username and role.
What is the proper way of getting and storing this data so that it is accessible globally? I want to be able to use this username in multiple components and ive tried doing it via context.
--
As a reply on luk2302
let jwtdata= jwtDecode<JwtPayload>(cookies.get("at"));
console.log(jwtdata["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"]);

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"' can't be used to index type 'JwtPayload'.
Property 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name' does not exist on type 'JwtPayload'.
trying to access the data like this gives me this error, eventhough it clearly exists. JwtPayload only lets me access expirey date and audience etc. It also gives a lot of issues (for me i'm still relatively new to typescript) to save the user data in a state and context.
—
So what is the correct way of reading a Jwt and storing that users data to use within other components, such as a profile component?

In what way does typescript make it impossible? Simply access the values based on claim keys.

@luk2302 added my reply into the question
